# C# asp.net webapi return default custom error response with custom error model

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am not an expert in asp.net webapi and trying to return some custom errorresponse with a custom error model. Please find below my code. Is this the right approach? basically i have a custom errormodel which i need it to be returned in case of any exception in webapi.

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string assetId)
    {
        _logProvider.Info($"AssetId - {assetId}");

        try
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return Request.CreateCustomResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, exception.Message);
        }
    }

public static class ApiExtensions
{
    public static HttpResponseMessage CreateCustomResponse(this HttpRequestMessage request, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string errorMessage)
    {
        var errorMessageModel = new ErrorModel(statusCode, errorMessage);

        return request.CreateResponse(statusCode, errorMessageModel);
    }
}



public class ErrorModel
{
    public ErrorModel(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
    {
        Code = (int)statusCode;
        Message = message;
        Fields = new Dictionary<string, ModelErrorCollection>();
    }

    public ErrorModel(HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    {
        Code = (int)statusCode;
        Fields = new Dictionary<string, ModelErrorCollection>();
    }

    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, ModelErrorCollection> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `HttpResponseException` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to see some example with custom error model?